# Offline mode with azure mobile JS SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm creating a react native app. For my use case it probably makes more sense to use the JavaScript sdk. The main reason is that I don't have to write custom code for android and ios.

However, since the js sdk is for the browser, I'm assuming that there's no offline mode? If not, any strategies (that minimize android and ios specific code)?

Answer (score 0):

We don't support React Native right now, and there are known issues with using the JavaScript SDK with React Native. (Example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues/193).

You can express your interest by watching https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues/195, which I filed to track this requirement.